# Does Kafka API and/or protocol offer a way to query for server properties?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm writing a Kafka producer that will on occasion send a request with a batch of messages that exceeds the maximum allowable request size.  It seems I don't have direct access to the server properties for the Kafka cluster to which I'm sending messages, and I haven't found a way to query the server for the values set in the `server.properties` file(s).

## Example

Attempting to send a message that's too large will trigger a Kafka log saying...

```
11:47:37 kafka.1     | Topic and partition to exceptions: 
page-visits-0 -> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException 
(kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KafkaAdminClient](http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/apache/kafka/1.1.0/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html) API to get cluster information. It can give Broker level as well as topic level information.  Below code will give server configuration for each node.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Config;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeClusterResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeConfigsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Node;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigResource;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigResource.Type;


public class ListTopics {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");
        AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(prop);
        DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = admin.describeCluster();
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(describeClusterResult.nodes().get());
        // Pass the broker node ID here. You can use for loop in case of multiple broker nodes.
        ConfigResource resource = new ConfigResource(Type.BROKER, String.valueOf(nodes.get(0).id()));

        DescribeConfigsResult configs = admin.describeConfigs(Collections.singletonList(resource));
        Map<ConfigResource, Config> config = configs.all().get();
        System.out.println(config   );
    }
}
```

P.S. This API can be used for Kafka 0.11 and above installations only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cluster is running Kafka 0.11 at least, you can use the AdminClient [`describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-) API to retrieve the broker configurations.

For example:

```java
Properties configs = new Properties();
configs.setProperty(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(configs);

List<ConfigResource> resources = Arrays.asList(new ConfigResource(Type.BROKER, "0"));
DescribeConfigsResult dcr = client.describeConfigs(resources);
for (Map.Entry<ConfigResource, Config> entry : dcr.all().get().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
```